# Spring security - GWT redirect after Authentication

Tags: gwt, spring-security

I have a GWT application that I am trying to login using spring security.  Currently, after a successful login, I am redirected back to the Login page.  I am guessing this is because of my spring configuration and my lack of spring security knowledge.

In my spring-security.xml I define my intercepts like so:

```
 <security:http auto-config="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    </security:http>
```

I am guessing that the issue is on the access=isAuthenticated() but I am not sure.  I want it to redirect to the gwt page/app which will handle the view based on the role returned.  I made a very simple gwt app with this method and it worked.

I am using the Spring generated login page and not a JSP.

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
    <security:http auto-config="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    </security:http>

    <b:bean id="graplAuthentication" class="com.foo.rim.security.GraplAuthentication"/>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="graplAuthentication" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

</b:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be two things.

1)  I needed to add the user-expressions="true" so it would pick up the access=

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
```

2) I had a custom user Authentication class and forgot to set the the Authenticated boolean to true.  Both of these got it working correctly.